# Problem with copying directory with .plugin package using node.js on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I'm creating an app - extension for Adobe software. This app is running in node.js environment. I want to copy and paste .plugin package (which is built using xcode) from extension directory to the software directory.

Using native Mac OS terminal I can easily copy and paste the plugin to the software directory (sudo cp -R). I wanted to replicate this using npm package "sudo-prompt" but it throws an error. I tried rsync also, it did not solve it.

My command:

```
cp -R "pathToMyPlugin" "/Library/Application Support/pathWhereIwantToPasteThePlugin"
```

Error:

```
unable to copy extended attributes to pathWhereIwantToPasteThePlugin: Operation not permitted
cp: pathWhereIwantToPasteThePlugin: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Hey @simplecreator did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not exactly, the workaround was to create a native installer @NoéMalzieu